# How to solve "java.sql.SQLException: Feature not implemented Query"?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java-6

I am trying to execute java application connecting with mysql but getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Feature not implemented Query: SELECT id, name, active, modified_time, create_time, version, last_modified_by, description, enc_type, settings_blob FROM projects WHERE active=true Parameters: []
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:363)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:350)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:225)
at azkaban.project.JdbcProjectLoader.fetchAllActiveProjects(JdbcProjectLoader.java:118)
... 6 more
```

Same application is working fine on most of the local servers but this error is occuring on main server. I am not able to find the reason for same. Please anyone tell me where I could move further as have no hint.
It is open source azkaban2 application I am trying to execute.Source code on location https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban2

Thanks!!!!

Comment: It might be version difference, that the main server has somewhere an older version (jre/lib/ext, webserver lib dirs). "Feature" hints at something like a bidirectional cursor or other more modern technique.

Comment: Java, jdk and mysql versions are same.Is there something else I should verify for?

Comment: If even the mysql config file is the same, maybe the locale's charset is different, and the config file cannot be read with that locale. Look in the logs too. For sanity make a dump of the database (schema, without data), and compare that to another server (correct dbengine etc.). JDBC connection strings? Try narrowing down that "feature", try mysql> commandline; for instance getting info.

Comment: Post the code and the full stacktrace, because now you are hiding the exception from the driver or the server.

Comment: I have updated the question with link of github source code